# hibernate filter not working in the case of session.get() but working in the case of session.createQuery()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using hibernate 4. I am writing a filter. The strange thing I noticed is the filter is not getting applied if I use session.get() method

```
public SecurityAgency getSecurityAgencyById(int id) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.enableFilter("byEnabled");
        SecurityAgency s = (SecurityAgency)session.get(SecurityAgency.class, new Integer(id));

         return s;
    }
```

Filter starts working as soon as I replace the session.get method with session.createQuery method and send a HQL query. I am unable to find any reason for this behaviour in the hibernate documentation.

FIlter declaration in securtiy agency class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="security_agency")

public class SecurityAgency  implements java.io.Serializable {
 @Id
 @Column(name = "id")
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private int id;
 @Column(name="name")
 private String name;
 @Column(name="code")
 private String code;
 @Column(name="website")
 private String website;
 @Column(name="tan")
 private String tan;
 @Column(name="email")
 private String email;
 @Column(name="pan")
 private String pan;
 @Column(name="created_at")
 private Date createdAt;
 @Column(name="created_by")
 private long createdBy;
 @Column(name="modified_at")
 private Date modifiedAt;
 @Column(name="modified_by")
 private long modifiedBy;
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="securityAgency",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JsonIgnoreProperties("securityAgency")

 @Filter(name = "byEnabled", condition = "is_enabled= 1")
 private Set<ContactPerson> contactPersons = new HashSet<ContactPerson>(0);

public SecurityAgency() {
}
```

Contact person class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contact_person")
@FilterDefs({
    @FilterDef(name="byEnabled"),
    @FilterDef(name="bySecurityAgency",parameters =       @ParamDef(name="agency_id", type="int"))
})
@Filters({
    @Filter(name="byEnabled", condition = "is_enabled = 1"),
    @Filter(name="bySecurityAgency", condition = "agency_id= :agency_id ")
})
public class ContactPerson  implements java.io.Serializable {
```

Comment: can you show your filter definition

Comment: @kuhajeyan. i am editing the question . but 4th comment on this blog stated that hibernate ignore filters in case of get and load https://ayende.com/blog/3993/nhibernate-filters.  but i cannot find such in any documentation

Comment: it should work with get fine, unless you have marked it disabled. Can you show your SecurityAgency class and how the filter is applied

Comment: i want to apply filters on contact persons nested in security agency. i am using eager loading to load the results. this is the whole code i have written for filter

Comment: where does is_enabled belong to?

Comment: this is a boolean column in contact person table. look at last third line in security agency class

Answer (score 2):

Filter doesn't work if you are fetching using id value.Use Query interface instead. See [this thread](https://coderanch.com/t/543756/databases/Hibernate-Filter-working)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use table column values you need to use filter join  table ( @FilterJoinTable ),  @Filter is applied to target entity rather than table

try,

```
@FilterJoinTable(name = "byEnabled", condition = "is_enabled= :enabled")
private Set<ContactPerson> contactPersons = new HashSet<ContactPerson>(0);
```

get

```
 session.enableFilter("byEnabled").setParameter("enabled",  Integer.valueOf(1));
```

Comment: and are you sure you want @Filters
@Filters({
    @Filter(name="byEnabled", condition = "is_enabled = 1"),
    @Filter(name="bySecurityAgency", condition = "agency_id= :agency_id ")
})
 to be applied on ContactPerson?

Comment: this one to many relation. contact person has agency_id column as foreign key to security agency table. this is working good if i use
String hql = "from SecurityAgency where id = " + id;
session.createQuery(hql).